# Rails 3 & Kaminari pagination problem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, pagination, rubygems, kaminari

Ok so I have decided to use Kaminari for pagination in a rails 3 project.  I have followed the video from RailsCasts http://railscasts.com/episodes/254-pagination-with-kaminari

All goes well up until the point or running the server.

**controllers/stories_controller.rb**

```
def index
   @stories = Story.all
   @pages = Story.page(params[:page]).per(3)
   @stories = Story.search(params[:search]) 
end
```

**views/stories/index.html.erb**

```
<%= paginate @pages %>
```

When i start the server the index page in question displays **all** the stories from the DB and renders the pagination view showing (1 2 Next > Last »).  What am I missing to get the pagination working?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I still can not understand your code. Why do you assign Story.all to @stories in the 1st line and overwrite the variable in the 3rd line?

Anyways, @stories will display "all the stories from the DB" because you're not calling the pagination method (`.per`) on @stories. The pagination links will show you the paginated counts because you're calling `per` method on @page variable and passing it to the helper.

I mean, you need to call `.per` on the relation before passing it to `<%= paginate %>` helper.
It's quite simple.

Comment: Hi ok, I have moved `Story.page(params[:page]).per(3)` to the bottom. pagination now works, but now my search doesn't.

Answer (score 3):

I guess you want to get results from your search, right?
Try

```
@stories = Story.search(params[:search]).page(params[:page]).per(3)
```

and something like:

```
<% @stories.each do |story| %>
<%= render story %>
<% end %>
<%= paginate @stories %>
```

in your view

Comment: Hi sorry, should have mentioned im trying to paginate the full result set as well

Comment: So paginating @pages doesn't work, right? Try to rename @pages into @mypages and see if it will be better.

Comment: Ok so having changed that and my .per(3) to a larger number it does in fact not show that pagination links which would suggest that the pagination is working behind the scenes... just not displaying them correctly at the frontend

Comment: if i change `<%= paginate @pages %>` to `<%= paginate @stories %>` i get an error **undefined method `current_page'**

Comment: Could you please update your question and write below initial one what your controller and view look like after all changes you made? I feel like we need to rewrite the whole thing for you and explain it finally :)